# SQL Select string not immediately preceded nor succeeded by other letters

Tags: sql-server

Imagine the following data:

```
Peter Santos (SA)
John Doe - SA
Maria Santos
```

I would like to match strings containing the letters SA, but not if they're inside a word.

In other words, when evaluating "Peter **Sa**ntos (**SA**)", it should fail on "**Sa**ntos" since it's succeeded by other letters, but succeed on (**SA**) since there are no letters preceding or succeeding it.

"John Doe - **SA**" should match the only SA entry there...

"Maria **Sa**ntos" should not return since it's succeeded by other characters.

How is this achievable using MS SQL without using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this query logic gives you what you need without using RegEx:

```
SELECT String_To_Search<br/>
FROM ...<br/>
WHERE <br/>
    String_To_Search LIKE 'SA[^A-Za-z]%'<br/>
    OR String_To_Search LIKE '%[^A-Za-z]SA'<br/>
    OR String_To_Search LIKE '%[^A-Za-z]SA[^A-Za-z]%'<br/>
```

The three predicates in the WHERE clause allow for 'SA' to appear at the beginning, middle, or end of the string, always neither preceded or followed by any letters.